# Maven release goals binding

Tags: maven, release, maven-release-plugin

I'd like to write a redmine plugin to update the version of some projects when they are released. To avoid manual steps, I'd like to bind to some of the release plugin execution goals. Typically, I need to create a new version when the version number is chosen, close the previous version before the new version is chosen, and so forth...

Now, I understand that the release phases are not part of the typical lifecycle, but I suspect that they can be "hooked" the same way as the other phases (like pre-integration-test or post-integartion-tests).

Here is what I tried:

```
<execution>
    <id>prepare-release-test</id>
    <phase>maven-release-plugin:prepare</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>list-issues</goal>
        <goal>list-versions</goal>
        <goal>list-users</goal>
        <goal>list-projects</goal>
    </goals>
```

```
<execution> 
    <id>prepare-test</id>
    <phase>maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>list-issues</goal>
        <goal>list-versions</goal>
        <goal>list-users</goal>
        <goal>list-projects</goal>
    </goals>
```

But none of those worked. WHen binding to test phase, it definelty works.

Comment: `prepare` is a standalone aggregator goal (executed only once for the whole project), you cannot "hook" it to any phase of lifecycle. You may also want to consider declaring your plugin goals as `@aggregator`.

Comment: What is the point of declaring it as aggregator? I found configurations for the release plugin allowing to run goals on completion and on preparation. Maybe those will be enough.

Comment: Sorry, here's the link: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/run-goals-before-commit.html

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that the release phases are not part of the typical lifecycle, but I suspect that they can be "hooked" the same way as the other phases.

They're not "phases". They're "goals", and the only way they're like phases is that you can pass their names to maven for execution. You can't bind goals to other goals the way you bind them to phases. In general, the way you'd solve this is by defining a profile that you [activate manually or automatically](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html) that [modifies the default lifecycle bindings](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-maven-profiles.html#profiles-sect-overriding-pom). If you want to go all-out, you could [define your own lifecycle](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html#writing-plugins-sect-custom-lifecycle), too, but that seems like overkill. In the specific case of the release plugin, though, you also have the option of using the [`preparationGoals`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#preparationGoals) and [`goals`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#goals) properties to customize what happens during `release:prepare` and `release:perform`, respectively.

Comment: Yes I saw the release specifics hooks right after posting my question.  It solves part of my problem. Now the first question's code was actually in a profile and I could bin it to something like test when activated and I am now trying to find the proper activation code for release goals. I think the profile activated process is better suitable for my needs.

Comment: FYI there's also the completionGoals http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#completionGoals